# Manipulate BarChart with Mathematica

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

In the following minimal working example:

```
Manipulate[BarChart[{a,b}],{a,1,2},{b,1,2}]
```

I'd like to be able to control the size of the bars by using some sort of `Locator` property for manipulate i.e. change the vertical size of each bar by placing my mouse on the edge of the bar (ideally anywhere along its width).

Obviously, `Locator` won't work. Any ideas how to easily do this?

I want the value of the bar chart to dynamically update. In the above example, I would have `a, b` obey some constraint (like `a + b = 2` so whenever one changes the other does so accordingly).

-------- Answered --------

This was so that there's some playing with the Greek general election. I wanted to play with the latest poll results and vary them before the election on Sunday.

@Mike Honeychurch: You are right, barspacing doesn't change the locator positioning but the locators are off center like so (this is my output when I run your code):

[image: Mikes]

I assume you run a different version of Mathematica than me - I run 7, sorry, should have said so. So, I had to fiddle with the x-coordinates of your locators in some way like this when defining `pt`:
    `numberofpoints = 5; 
    barspacing = 0.1;
    xcoords = Table[i + barspacing i - 1/2, {i, 1,   numberofpoints}];
    pt = xcoords~Riffle~RandomInteger[{0, 3}, 3]~Partition~2`

I got the chart to look OK at the end (locators here for only the first three bars):

[image: Mikes to mine]

but wasn't entirely happy with the way it was done because of the fiddling I mentioned above. So I am going with @Heike 's approach that works a treat out of the box exactly the way I wanted:

```
lastpoll = {{LightBlue, 24.3, "ΝΔ"}, {Green, 15.4, "ΠΑΣΟΚ"}, {Red, 10.9, "ΚΚΕ"}, 
{Yellow, 8, "ΔΗΜΑΡ"}, { Pink, 9.5, "ΣΥΡΙΖΑ"}, {Blue, 9.6, "Αν. Ελληνες"},
{Gray, 6.3, "Χρυση Αυγη"}, {LightBlue, 4.2, "ΛΑΟΣ"}, {Green, 4.4, "Οικολογοι"}, 
{LightCyan, 2.1, "Δημ. Συμμαχια"}, {Yellow, .8, "ΕΠΑΜ"}, { LightRed, .8, "ΔΡΑΣΗ"},
{Blue, .8, "ΑΝΤΑΡΣΥΑ"}, {LightGray, .8, "Κοιν. Συμφωνια"}, {White, 2, "Λοιπα"}};
values = #[[2]] & /@ lastpoll;
dragBar[values, 
ChartLabels -> Placed[(Last /@ lastpoll), Axis, Rotate[#, 55 Degree] &],
ChartStyle -> (First /@ lastpoll), BarSpacing -> .6, ImageSize -> Large]
```

with the following result (all fiddlable):

[image]

In any case, thank you all for taking the time. This was harder than I expected it would be..

Comment: What does "MWE" mean?

Comment: Sorry, it stands for Minimal Working Example. It's not the code of what I want (as it's more complicated) but demonstrates the problem I have

Comment: Do you also need to use the bar heights in some other place in the Manipulate, or do you merely need resizable boxes?

Comment: So you want the bar height to be draggable in order to control a a variable dynamically? Or do you want the bar height to be dynamically controlled by the value of a variable?

Comment: @Jens (and Szabolics) I want the bar height to be draggable to control a variable dynamically. In the above example  from a starting value of a=1, b=1 I want to be able to drag the height  of bar "a" to 1.5 and see bar "b" reduce proportionally to 0.5

Comment: minimal working example translates to barely working example...

Comment: While Heike´s example works fine, your `lastpoll...` code is not interactive re dragging.

Comment: whoopsy - ran it without interactivity so that the bars don't move when I select the image. Should work now.

Comment: @gpap I am running 8.0.4. My output is obviously quite different to what you see in V7 which is a shame because my solution is straight forward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my attempt. The tricky part turned out to be to only change the height of a bar when the mouse cursor is close enough to its top edge. By default, the vertical distance between the mouse cursor and the top edge needs to be less than .5 in order to drag the bar. You can change this value by setting the option `"resolution"`.

I've also implemented the constraint that the sum of the heights is constant so when one bar is dragged the heights of other bars change to keep the total height constant.

Note that `dragBar` accepts any option of `BarChart` so you can still use all the  features of `BarChart`.

```
SetAttributes[dragBar, HoldFirst];
Options[dragBar] = Append[Options[BarChart], "resolution" -> .5];

dragBar[values_, opt : OptionsPattern[dragBar]] := 
 DynamicModule[{widths, ind, pt = {0, 0}, index},
  widths = Reap[BarChart[ConstantArray[1, Length[values]], 
      ChartElementFunction :> ((If[Head[#1] === List, Sow[#1[[1]]]];) &), 
      FilterRules[{opt}, Options[BarChart]]]][[2, 1]];
  ind[x_] := Piecewise[
    Table[{i, widths[[i, 1]] < x < widths[[i, 2]]}, {i, Length[widths]}], 0];

  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt,
    {(index = ind[#[[1]]]; 
      If[index == 0 || Abs[#[[2]] - values[[index]]] > OptionValue["resolution"], 
        index = None]) &,
     (If[IntegerQ[index],
        values += (values[[index]] - #[[2]])/(Length[values] - 1);
        values[[index]] = #[[2]]]) &,
     None}],
   Dynamic[BarChart[values, FilterRules[{opt}, Options[BarChart]]]], Appearance -> None]]

values = RandomInteger[10, 10];
dragBar[values, BarSpacing -> .6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 13):

Here is something that ticks all the boxes (I think).

1. you use locators to change the height of the bars
2. you have a `BarChart` and can style it as you wish.
3. the controlling locator is centred on each bar
4. the sum of the heights is constrained -- in this case they sum to 5.

So let me know if this is what you are after:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}}, tmp, sum = 5},

 LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[pt, (tmp = #; 
     pt = {{1, sum - tmp[[2, 2]]}, {2, sum - tmp[[1, 2]]}}) &],

  Dynamic@BarChart[{pt[[1, 2]], pt[[2, 2]]},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
    PlotRange -> {{0.3, 2.5}, {0, 5}}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

**Edit**

`BarSpacing` does not effect the locator positioning:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, tmp},

 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (tmp = #;
     pt = {{1, tmp[[1, 2]]}, {2, tmp[[2, 2]]}, {3, tmp[[3, 2]]}}) &],

  Dynamic@BarChart[{pt[[1, 2]], pt[[2, 2]], pt[[3, 2]]},
    BarSpacing -> Large,
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
    PlotRange -> {{0.3, 3.5}, {0, 5}}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Mike: thanks - I think yours is my favourite so far although my problem is that still in defining the `Locator` you need to specify the x-coordinate for it which is extra information in `BarChart`. So, if I want to plot `n` bars in my chart I define some variable `barspacing` and add the x-coordinates to each locators as `Table[i + barspacing i - 1/2,{i,1,n}]` (in the middle) and then add `BarSpacing->barspacing` to the BarChart.

Anyway, I'll give it until tonight to play more with it. The idea is to have a bar chart for all parties in the Greek general election and fiddle with their %s.

Comment: As per my edit the setting for `BarSpacing` does not change your locater positioning. The locator will always be centred. The edited example is not constrained but you can add a constraint with "n" bars as per the first example by e.g. for the first bar `sum - tmp[[2, 2]] -tmp[[3, 2]] - tmp[[n,2]]` and so on.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another sketch:

```
DynamicModule[{a, b, ab, val},
 {a, b} = {1, 1};
 ab[{x_, y_}] := Which[
   0.2 <= x <= 1.2, {a = y, b = 2 - a},
   1.2 <= x <= 2.4, {a = 2 - y, b = y},
   True, {a, b}
   ];
 Dynamic@BarChart[{val = ab@MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}]},
   PlotRange -> {-10, 10},
   BarSpacing -> None,
   ChartLabels -> {val}
   ]
 ]
```

The chart changes dynamically when you move over the bars, no need to click. The dependence `a+b=2` is implemented as well.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Does this give you the basis for a solution:

```
Manipulate[
 Framed@Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, Last@p}], Blue, 
    Rectangle[{1.1, 0}, {2.1, Last@q}]}], {{p, {1, 1}}, 
  Locator}, {{q, {1.1, 2}}, Locator}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Well, kind of but ideally want to use some of the native labelling and spacing within `BarChart` and trying to use the `Locator` the way you do doesn't quite work. The bars in `BarChart` have varied widths depending on how you space them so a `Locator`'s x-coordinate can vary in a BarChart. Also I was hoping the equivalent of the `Locator` cross could be the entire upper line (just for aesthetic reasons).

Comment: At the moment I believe you can click on any part of the "bar" and adjust it's height. Normally the `Locator` symbol can be set to none (or replaced with something else ) , but I couldn't quite work out how to do that here. Maybe someone else knows how.

Comment: @image_doctor you can append control options inside a variable specification: {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}